# Which is the class that parse persistence annotations?

Tags: java

Given an implementation of the Persistence specification (EclipseLink,for example),How do I find the source code of the class which parse persistence annotations in a code like `@Entity`, for example?

Comment: There is no one class for that. It's done by the Java EE container, and there are lots of different implementations of Java EE containers.

Answer (score 2):

`@Entity` and friends are part of [JPA, the Java Persistence API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API). JPA is just a standard, and there are multiple implementations conforming to that standard. So, the answer to your question depends on which JPA implementation you're using.

If you're just looking for *an* example, I would look at [EclipseLink, which is the reference implementation](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/). You can find a copy of the [runtime's source code on GitHub.](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipselink.runtime)

Comment: I know that...but, where in the EclipseLink, for example, do I find the exact class that deal with these kind of annotations?

Comment: @BrunoBarros who says there's just one class? `:)` I strongly encourage you to read the code.

Comment: The purpose is exactly that. Study the code that parses these annotations.

Comment: For instance, what is the class in the EclipseLink implementation that reads the annotation @Entity and process it?

Comment: Start here: https://github.com/eclipse/eclipselink.runtime/tree/master/jpa/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa/src/org/eclipse/persistence

Answer (score 1):

the place i normally use to search for any java source code online is ,
[Grep Code](http://grepcode.com/search/?query=entity)

As Matt suggested, `@Entity` is interface of JPA and there would be
many implementations vendors like Hibernate,Eclipse Link etc.,